# can't configure data for CORS due to other email being associated with project

Tags: firebase, cors, firebase-storage, gsutil

I am trying to configure my google storage for Firebase to allow cross origin uploading using `gsutil` and a `cors.json`file.  I enter the following command in my project where the cors file is located:

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://nameofproject.appspot.com
```

I get the following error message:

```
AccessDeniedException: 403 someOtherFirebaseAccount@gmail.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to bucket apptotest.appspot.com
```

I am not currently logged in with `someOtherFirebaseAccount` -- I verify this by running `firebase login` and seeing that my current, desired account is the active one.

```
firebase login
Already logged in as desiredAccount@gmail.com
```

Any ideas what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the version of gsutil that comes packaged with gcloud, it will use credentials for your currently logged in gcloud user (this is usually the last user you activated via `gcloud auth login`).  You can check which user is active by running `gcloud auth list`.

If you're **not** using the gcloud-packaged version of gsutil, you can run `gsutil config` and log in as the desired user.